# Foreign key record in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have recently started using Entity Framework and have run into a problem.

I have 2 simple tables mapped with Entity Framework in my solution:

**Employees**:

```
emp_id INT
first_name VARCHAR
last_name VARCHAR
department INT ( FOREIGN KEY MAPPED TO departments.dept_id )
```

and

**Departments**:

```
dept_id INT
department_name VARCHAR
```

Using the code below, I want to write to the database.

```
var record = db.employees.Create();

string test = "test";

record.first_name = test;
record.last_name = test;
record.department = 1;

db.employees.Add(record);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error the error:

> Entities in "'DBContextContainer.employees' participate in the 'employeedepartment' relationship. 0 related 'department' were found. 1 'department' is expected."

at the `db.SaveChanges()` method. Can someone please explain to me how I could resolve or troubleshoot this?

**Update:** There is a record in the departments table with a `dept_id` of 1 and I am still getting the error.

Comment: Is there an existing department with an ID of 1 in the Departments table?

Comment: Yes, There is a record in the departments table with a dept_id of 1

Comment: show us the content of the database? EntityFramework is not able to find the Department with `dept_id` 1 for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a field to the `Departments` table first since `Departments` is the parent table (Employees depend on Departments as per your table structure). You cant add an `employee` with `department` that doesn't have a corresponding entry in the `Departments` table.

Comment: Hi, I have already done. There is a record in the departments table with a dept_id of 1

Comment: @user3648426 why is the department of `Employees` a varchar and `Departments` an int. They need to be the same.

Comment: Hi, my bad, I made an error in the post but have corrected it. It  (employees.department) is actually an INT in both my model and on db.